# Dynamic layout with faded borders

Tags: html, css, layout, fluid

I am working on bringing a designed webpage layout to life. The design may be a little unusual so I am not sure whether it is possible to achieve. Basically, I will have a fixed-width content box of 900px. The content box will be positioned in the middle of the page body. I want to add two vertical columns to the page with fading pngs. The left png will face from solid black on the left to transparent on the right. The right png will fade from solid black on the right to transparent on the left. The two pngs will be 250px wide each. Once everything is positioned, the layout should look like a paper that has faded on the left and right edges. However, the trick is in re-sizing the page. I would like to make sure that when the screen is less than 1500px wide (both of the columns are partially outside of the screen), the columns do not slide under the content box but simply shrink to zero. Please, consider the images below. Black outline is the screen, blue is the content, and red are the columns. When the screen is 1500px wide, the columns and content are aligned well. The illusion (without borders) is of a fading image. ![Layout when screen is 1500px wide][1] When the screen is stretched, the columns grow apart and still the faded look is kept. ![Layout when screen is more than 1500px wide][2] Finally, when the screen is less than 1500px wide, the columns shrink but the background image of each column is attached in a way that does not break the faded look (for example, it would be incorrect for left column to shrink and black get closer to the left side of the content box). ![Layout when screen is less than 1500px wide][3]

** Could not post images :(

Comment: Just upload an image somewhere else and post a link to it if you need images.

Answer (score 0):

Best would to be a mix of jquery and css3.

Jquery will alow you to keep the Main content centered and have a div on both sides. While CSS3 will allow you to have a gradient on both sides with no need for images. Only down side is that if the browser is not CSS3 compliant it will not show the gradient. Only one that is not compliant is IE8 and earlier. But there are addons that will help (Modenizr and IE Chrome Tab)

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 windowWidth = $(window).width();
 divWidth = (windowWidth - 900) / 2;
 $('#left_container').css({width: divWidth+"px"});
 $('#right_container').css({width: divWidth+"px"});
});

$(window).resize(function() {
 windowWidth = $(window).width();
 divWidth = (windowWidth - 900) / 2;
 $('#left_container').css({width: divWidth+"px"});
 $('#right_container').css({width: divWidth+"px"});
});
```

Left Div CSS

```
background-image: linear-gradient(90 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
 linear,
 90 90,
 right 90,
 color-stop(0, #FFFFFF),
 color-stop(0.52, #000000)
);
```

Right Div CSS

```
background-image: linear-gradient(270 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(270 , #FFFFFF 0%, #000000 52%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
 linear,
 270 270,
 left 270,
 color-stop(0, #FFFFFF),
 color-stop(0.52, #000000)
);
```